# Laravel - Eloquent - Polymorphic relationships with namespaces

Tags: laravel, polymorphism, eloquent, laravel-5

I have 2 tables related by a polimorphic relationship:

The Store table:

```
id  |  name     |   ... 
15  |  my_store |   ...
```

And the Tag table, that is connected to the Store table through the related_id key and the type.

```
id  |  related_id  |  tag   |  created  |  type  
1   |  15          |  test  |  00:00:00 |  store
2   |  15          |  dummy |  00:00:00 |  product
```

So, in that example, the Store "my_store" only has the tag "test" ("dummy" is a tag for a product, not a Store, besides it has the same related_id).

I have the Store model defined in my code as follows:

```
class Store extends Model {

protected $table = 'store';

public function tags()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Tag', 'related', 'type');
}
}
```

And the tag model:

```
class Tag extends Model {

protected $table = 'tags';

public function related()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
}
```

But when I try to run

```
$store->tags;
```

I saw that the query that Laravel is trying to run is:

```
SQL: select * from `mwp_tags` where `mwp_tags`.`related_id` = 46 
and `mwp_tags`.`related_id` is not null 
and `mwp_tags`.`type` = App\Store)
```

The query is looking for **App\Store** instead of **store**

I cannot change the value in DB and I wouldn't like to use the

```
    protected $morphClass = 'store';
```

inside the Store model as I don't know if a would have to create another  morphMany relationship, probably with another type name.

Somebody knows how to skip this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Laravel needs it as `App\Store` so it knows which class to load it as.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
public function tags()
{
    $default_morph_class = $this->morphClass ?: null;
    $this->morphClass = 'store';
    $morph_many_query = $this->morphMany('App\Tag', 'related', 'type');
    $this->morphClass = $default_morph_class;
    return $morph_many_query;
}
```

The idea being you change the morphClass on the fly and set it back. That allows you to use a different morphClass for a different relationship.

Comment: Excelent, this works for me. But now I need that the reverse-relationship in the Tag model also works:
`public function related()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}`

Comment: `$this->morphTo('related', 'type');` is looking for the model **store** because appears with that name in the DB, but in Laravel is defined as **App\Store**